# Plot inside for loop but only every x-second / x-iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

I've got a for-loop and compute some graphs in it.
The number of iterations are pretty high (>100000), so I don't want to plot every "frame", but taking a "snapshot" every e.g. 10ms or 10000 iteration as a plot (update same figure). It doesn't have to be accurate.

Is there any function for this kind of problem available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normally achieved by using the [modulo operation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) as a condition inside your loop. Keeping a counter variable that increments by `1` at each loop iteration, use:

```
if mod(counter, period) == 0
    % update your plot
end
```

to run your update code only every `period` iterations. So if you want to update your plot every `1000` iterations then

```
period = 1000;
for counter = 1:100000
    % your calcs
    if mod(counter, period) == 0
        % update your plot
    end
end
```

Comment: This is the simplest and best way to do it.  I would add that in many cases when I have captured these "evolving" data snapshots, I have made movies to be able to easily comprehend the changes over time.  You can use MATLAB builtins `getframe()` and `movie()` to very easily turn these figure snapshots into a movie.  See examples here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html

Comment: Also the [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html?searchHighlight=drawnow) function is sometimes useful